# Airflow settings to run Celery workers in different Docker container?

Tags: docker, celery, airflow

I am running Airflow in docker container. I have created a separate container to run Postgres server and Rabbitmq server, connected these containers using docker network - by following this nice [article](https://stlong0521.github.io/20161023%20-%20Airflow.html). Now my Airflow docker container is running and connected to other containers using docker network - the process went smooth so far. The problem is how to run `airflow webserver`, `airflow scheduler` and `airflow worker` in the same container. After some research I found: it is recommended to run one service in one container. Now I have two solutions

1. Run multiple services in the same Airflow container - which I could not figure out a simple way implement being a new bee in Docker.
2. Create separate containers to run Celery worker and Airflow scheduler - but in the airflow.cfg file the setting related to Celery are: `broker_url = 'amqp://guest:guest@ksaprice_rabbitmq:8080//'`, `celery_result_backend = db+postgresql://developer:user889@ksaprice_postgres:5432/airflow`. These settings refer to either database or rabbitmq which are already running different containers - they do not refer to ip/url which runs celery and scheduler and I assuming it is this way because celery and scheduler runs on the airflow server.

My questions are:

1. Reffering to point 1: Is there a simple way to run `airflow webserver`, `airflow scheduler` and `airflow worker` commands in the same Airflow container?
2. Refferring to point 2: Is there a way in airflow.cfg to configure airflow scheduler and airflow worker to run in separate docker containers - and link them using docker network?

I am new bee to Airflow and Docker.

Comment: Why don't you look at this url https://hub.docker.com/r/puckel/docker-airflow/ and use this image to setup the whole thing?

Comment: Does this work with python 2.7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After spending lot of time I found the following answers:

1. For the first question:
     To run multiple services on the same airflow_container do: `docker exec -it airflow_container bash`, now CLI will be attached to airflow_container then  run `airflow worker`. Repeat the same process for `airflow scheduler` and `airflow flower`. Now you will have three different CLIs running three services on the same airflow_container - this is the simplest way I found .
2. For the second question: There are options here:[airflow cli](https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/cli.html)  like `airflow webserver --hostname=some_host --port=some_port` and `airflow flower --hostname=some_host --port=some_port` to run them on different severs. But for `airflow worker` there are no options to run  on different server - may be there is some other way to run worker on different server.

Answer (score 0):

1- I did install all of these so its possible

2-  optimized way is to install airflow(webserver) + backend-DB(Mysql) on one server, queuing(RabbitMQ) on another and Celery part on other set of servers.
bellow I will mention something from the source and can be helpful to clarify things a bit better:

> CeleryExecutor is one of the ways you can scale out the number of
> workers. For this to work, you need to setup a Celery backend
> (RabbitMQ, Redis, …) and change your airflow.cfg to point the executor
> parameter to CeleryExecutor and provide the related Celery settings.
>
> Here are a few imperative requirements for your workers:
>
> airflow needs to be installed, and the CLI needs to be in the path
>
> Airflow configuration settings should be homogeneous across the
> cluster
>
> Operators that are executed on the worker need to have their
> dependencies met in that context. For example, if you use the
> HiveOperator, the hive CLI needs to be installed on that box, or if
> you use the MySqlOperator, the required Python library needs to be
> available in the PYTHONPATH somehow
>
> The worker needs to have access to its DAGS_FOLDER, and you need to
> synchronize the filesystems by your own means. A common setup would be
> to store your DAGS_FOLDER in a Git repository and sync it across
> machines using Chef, Puppet, Ansible, or whatever you use to configure
> machines in your environment. If all your boxes have a common mount
> point, having your pipelines files shared there should work as well

Source: https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/1.10.6/howto/executor/use-celery.html